# How can I set data in html table by using php and mysql variables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm selecting data in mysql database by using concat,group_concat and mysql variable but I failed to execute those data in html table (on browser) by using PHP while I'm getting those data in mysql cmd.

Take a look about my query and how it is running in mysql cmd

```
<?php

$ma=mysqli_query($con,
    "SELECT CONCAT(
  'SELECT `marks`.regno', GROUP_CONCAT('
     ,    `t_', REPLACE(mcode, '`', '``'), '`.total
         AS `', REPLACE(mcode, '`', '``'), '`'
     SEPARATOR ''),
 ' FROM `marks` ', GROUP_CONCAT('
     LEFT JOIN `marks`   AS `t_', REPLACE(mcode, '`', '``'), '`
            ON `marks`.regno = `t_', REPLACE(mcode, '`', '``'), '`.regno
           AND `t_', REPLACE(mcode, '`', '``'), '`.mcode = ', QUOTE(mcode)
     SEPARATOR ''),
 ' GROUP BY `marks`.regno'
) INTO @qry FROM (SELECT DISTINCT mcode FROM `marks`  where level=1 AND sem=2) t"


);

$mar=mysqli_query($con,"PREPARE stmt FROM @qry") ;
$marks=mysqli_query($con, "EXECUTE stmt");

?>
```

HTML:

```
<table>

        <?php
        while ($read=mysqli_fetch_array($marks)) {

        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $read['regno'];  ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $read['mcode'];  ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Output in MariaDB Monitor:

```
+-----------+--------+--------+
| regno     | ICT103 | ICT104 |
+-----------+--------+--------+
| 16RP00508 |     61 |     61 |
| 16RP00509 |     63 |     63 |
| 16RP00510 |     65 |     65 |
| 16RP00511 |     67 |     67 |
| 16RP00512 |     69 |     69 |
| 16RP00513 |     84 |     71 |
+-----------+--------+--------+
```

I am getting only regno in browser, help me how can I get mcode and total like this output Im getting in cmd.

take a look what I get in browser
[This is my Output in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euOM9.jpg)

Comment: Wow, creating a SELECT query with a SELECT query. That's ambitious. I have no idea what these queries, in the end, accomplish. My best guess is that you have over complicated things. Do you realize that MySQLi has a [prepare()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) method?

Comment: `var_dump($read)` to see what you get. It looks like you don't assign aliases to GROUP_CONCATG expressions.

Comment: You are preparing a MySQL query using MySQL queries. That is not the right approach. You can use PHP to prepare a query. See: [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Post the output of the query

Comment: @Naktibalda thanks It seems like var_dump will handle it, but it keep display unwanted things like array, string, ...

Comment: @mistico: var_dump is a debugging tool, use it to understand what keys you get in the $read array.